# How to hide marker value in map if the markers value has been generated in the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, leaflet

The code that gets the location and other information where the name field equals 'VAWC':

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=poi', 'root', ''); 
$sql = "SELECT name,user_date,user_time,address,lat,lng,icon_name FROM tblmarker where name = 'VAWC'"; 

$rs = $db->query($sql); 
if (!$rs) { 
    echo "An SQL error occured.\n"; 
    exit; 
} 

$rows = array(); 
while($r = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $rows[] = $r; 
    $name[] = $r['name'];
    $user_date[] = $r['user_date'];
    $user_time[] = $r['user_time'];
    $address[] = $r['address'];
    $icon_name[] = $r['icon_name'];
} 
print json_encode($rows); 
$db = NULL; 
?>
```

Ajax request that fetches the data and generates the markers:

```
var vawc = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '../legends/7.gif',
        iconSize:     [50, 50], // size of the icon
    iconAnchor:   [23, 50], // point of the icon which will correspond to marker's location
    popupAnchor:  [3, -50] // point from which the popup should open relative to the iconAnchor
});

function getInfo6() { 
    $.getJSON("datalegends/vawc.php", function (data) { 
      for (var e = 0; e < data.length; e++) { 
        var location6 = new L.LatLng(data[e].lat, data[e].lng); 
        var marker6 = new L.Marker(location6,{icon:vawc}); 
           marker6.bindPopup(
              data[e].name + "<br>" + 
               data[e].user_date + "<br>" + 
               data[e].user_time + "<br>" + 
               data[e].address + "<br>"
           ).addTo(map);
           marker6.on('click', function(e) { // HERE YOU GO
                var vawc = marker6.getLatLng();
document.querySelector('#userLat1').value = vawc.lat;
document.querySelector('#userLng1').value = vawc.lng;
           });
         } 
    }); 
  }
```

The code to generate markers on page load:

```
<body onload="javascript:start();">
<font face="century gothic" color="black" size="2px">
<script>
function start() {
    getInfo();
    getInfo1();
    getInfo2();
    getInfo3();
    getInfo4();
    getInfo5();
    getInfo6();
}
</script>
```

My question is how can I hide that marker in the map using this code

```
<li><input style="width:18px;height:18px;" type="checkbox" checked="True">&nbsp&nbsp Arson</li></br>
```

Simple question - if I check it the marker will show, if I uncheck it the marker will hide.

I dont know how to do it because it comes from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put markers which belong together in one group:

```
// Create group and add to map
var group = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(map);

$.getJSON('markers.json', function (data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
        var marker = new L.Marker(location);
        // Add marker to group
        group.addLayer(marker);
    }
});
```

Put an onchange handler on your input:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="toggleGroup(this)" checked>Toggle group</li>
```

Then add a function to handle the onchange event:

```
function toggleGroup (e) {
    // Is checked
    if (e.checked) {
        // Add group to map
        map.addLayer(group);
    // Isn't checked
    } else {
        // Remove group from map
        map.removeLayer(group);
    }
}
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cSUVCW?p=preview

Comment: Can you set some example using my code? i try it seems not working for me. ty

Comment: No thanks, you're always welcome. This is pretty much your code, i've changed some variable names so it reads more easily and i've left out your popup and clickhandler, for the rest it's the same. Good luck with your project. PS. You might want to take a look at this tutorial on layerGroups with the corresponding controls, i think it's what you're trying to accomplish: [http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html)

Comment: Nice to hear that actually im creating an online mapping and all of it comes from leaflet :D